# Longtable breaking into very small sections over many pages.

Tags: tables, longtable, journal-publishing, journal

I'm writing a paper in the format of Monthly Notices of the Royal Astronomical Society (MNRAS- mn2e). I seem to be having quite a few issues with my tables for it. I have several long tables that spans over more than one page. I have tried the longtable package but this causes the table to be split into many small sections spanning over many pages. Also the table doesn't center in the page and the captions don't appear.

[image]

My Preamble is:

```
 \RequirePackage{rotating} %for rotating (landscaping) tables
 \documentclass[useAMS,usenatbib]{mn2e}
%\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{article} %showframe

% set up sensible margins (same as for cssethesis)
%\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,width=150mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]      {geometry}

%\usepackage{setspace} % Word spacing
%\singlespacing %(or \doublespacing  \onehalfspacing)

\usepackage{txfonts}

\usepackage{mathtools} % can add [fleqn]: fleqn argument shifts equations to the left rather than centred
\usepackage{amssymb} % adds math symbols easily 
 \usepackage[load-configurations=astronomy]{siunitx} % astro symbols made easy. eg: \num{2e-4} \si{\kilo\metre} \SI{2e-4}{\kilo\metre\per\second}

 \DeclareSIUnit\parsec{pc}
  \DeclareSIUnit\kilo{K}
   \DeclareSIUnit\ergs{ergs}
   \usepackage[version=3]{mhchem} % chem symbols made easy eg: \ce{H20}
    %\numberwithin{equation}{section} %gives eqns as 1.1 in section 1 and 2.1 in section 2 and so on. 

 \usepackage{graphicx} % Helps with graphics and tables 
  %\usepackage[width=0.8\textwidth]{caption} % justification=centering,Captions on figures labelfont=bf,font=it,
 \usepackage{float}
  \usepackage{subfigure}
   \usepackage{subcaption} %subcaptions on figures
    %\numberwithin{figure}{section}

   \usepackage{titlesec}
    \titlespacing\section{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
    \titlespacing\subsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}
     \titlespacing\subsubsection{0pt}{12pt plus 4pt minus 2pt}{6pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

     \usepackage{morefloats}

     \usepackage{lscape}
      \usepackage{pdflscape}

      %\usepackage{afterpage}
       %\newcommand\blankpage{%
        %\null
       %\thispagestyle{empty}%
       %\addtocounter{page}{-1}%
       %\newpage}


       \usepackage{color}

         %\usepackage{pdfpages}

          \usepackage{perpage} %the perpage package
           \MakePerPage{footnote} %the perpage package command


             \usepackage [author year, colon, round]{natbib}                
             %\usepackage{bibtex} % Use the natbib bibliography and citation package (author, year style, with round brackets)
              \usepackage{hyperref} % hyperlinks to reference

          \usepackage{booktabs} 
          \usepackage{multirow}
          \usepackage{array}
          \usepackage{longtable}
           \usepackage{tabu}
            \usepackage{threeparttable} %table with notes
             \usepackage{threeparttablex} %longtable with notes
             \usepackage{rotating}
              \usepackage{xtab}
               \usepackage{multicol}

              \usepackage[title,titletoc,toc]{appendix} % \appendix



        %\newcommand{\sol}[1]{\odot{#1}} % short code for sun symbol 
        % {$\mathrm{}$} = Math mode in non-italized form
         \newcommand{\textsubscript}[1]{$_\textrm{#1}$} %short code for subscripting
          \newcommand{\Ha}{H${\alpha}$} % short code for H-alpha
           \newcommand{\HB}{H$\beta$} % short code for H-beta
           \newcommand{\EHaHB}{E(H$\alpha$-H$\beta$)} % short code for E(Ha-HB)
            \newcommand{\CHa} {C$_{{\textrm{H}\alpha}}$} % short code for CHa
             \newcommand{\CHB}{C$_{{\textrm{H}\beta}}$} % short code for CH-beta
              \newcommand{\AV}{$\textrm{A}_{\textrm{V}}$} % short code for Av
               \newcommand{\Av}{$\textrm{A}_{\textrm{V}}$} % short code for Av
              \newcommand{\AvCHB}{A_{\textrm{V}}(\textrm{C}$_{{\textrm{H}\beta}}$)} % short code for Av(CH-beta)
               \newcommand{\AvCHa}{A_{\textrm{V}}(\textrm{C}$_{{\textrm{H}\alpha}}$)} % short code for Av(CH-alpha)
            \newcommand{\AvE}{A_{\textrm{V}}[\textrm{E}(\textrm{H}$\alpha$-\textrm{H}$\beta$)]} % short code for E(Ha-HB)
             \newcommand{\app}[1]{\textup{\textsc{\MakeLowercase{#1}}}}
              \newcommand{\comm}[1]{\texttt{#1}}

         \title[}
         \author[]
         \date{Received:}

         \begin{document}

          \maketitle

           \begin{abstract}
               .....
            \end{abstract}

           \begin{keywords}
             ......
            \end{keywords}


            \input{./Tables/Table1}


            %\include{Appendix}


             \bibliographystyle{chicago}
              \bibliography{fullbib}
               \end{document}
```

My table code is:

```
  \begin{longtable*}{llllllp{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}}
  \caption{....}
  \label{....}

   \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{PN}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{{\AvE}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{{\AV}(Radio)}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Weighted Averaged {\Av}}} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
    \cmidrule(lr) {3-4}
    \cmidrule(lr) {5-6}
    \cmidrule(lr) {7-8}
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{PN G}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\Av}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{unc.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\AV}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{unc.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\AV}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{unc.}} \\
     (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead

    \caption {continued..}
           \toprule
            \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{PN}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{{\AvE}}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\textbf{{\AV}(Radio)}} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{\textbf{Weighted Averaged {\Av}}} \\
            \cmidrule(lr){1-2}
            \cmidrule(lr) {3-4}
            \cmidrule(lr) {5-6}
            \cmidrule(lr) {7-8}
            \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{PN G}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{Name}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\Av}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{unc.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\AV}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{unc.}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{{\AV}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{\textbf{unc.}} \\
             (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) & (5) & (6) & (7) & (8)\\
            \hline
            \endhead

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{030.80+03.47} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{A 47} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{8.79} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.11} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{8.79} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.11} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{031.03+04.13} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{K 3-6} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{7.92} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{3.08} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{6.98} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.15} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{7.02} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.14} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{210.09+03.99} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{We 2- 34} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{-} \\

    \multicolumn{1}{l}{210.38+01.90} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{M 1- 8} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.49} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.32} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.47} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.21} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{2.48} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.13} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{212.03+04.36} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{M 1- 9} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.44} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.32} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.38} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.04} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{1.27} & \multicolumn{1}{l}{0.03} \\ 
    \......
    \bottomrule
\end{longtable*}
```

Comment: Please turn your preamble into something compilable

Comment: The document is a mess, sorry! And `longtable` does not work in two-column-mode, which seems to be the default of the MNRAS journals

Comment: @ChristianHupfer, It's fine, I agree it does need a lot of work.I'm pretty new to latex so it will take me some time to get the hang of it. MNRAS does set as for two col by default. If  long tables don't work for two col? is there another method to print multipage tables in two col mode? (Both potrait and rotated landscape multipage tables)

Comment: I did add \Requirepackage{longtable} before the \documentclass command. Now the table is printed all together (without being split into small parts) but as you said it's still single columned and overlaps with the text in the second column.

Comment: Is there any news here?